# Clarification on the state of the art of qubit commitment

Tags: commitments, quantum-cryptography

What is the current state of research on quibit commitment?

It seems that the answer is not [2001](http://b.itech.sk/public/pokus.pdf) but it seems to me that a lot of these pdf are referring to a old protocols of quantum bit commitment [1997](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9712023v1.pdf), where the impossibility of that scheme has been proved for a unconditionally (or perfect) security of qubit commitment. 
Other sources, such ash [2012](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379712000162) propose a practical version of qubit commitment which employs another protocol, and shows that qubit commitment can be indeed practically secure.

I have found [2015 (last update of the page)](https://quantiki.org/wiki/bit-commitment) these sentence that might be what I was definitely looking for:

> Bit commitment can be realized classically in an computationally
>   secure sense. More precisely, the protocols are either computationally
>   hiding (in which case it is only computationally secure from Alice's
>   point of view) or computationally binding (computationally secure from
>   Bob's point of view). Moreover, it is not hard to prove that
>   information-theoretically secure bit commitment protocols cannot exist
>   classically. Interestingly, it could be shown that the same is true if
>   we allow Alice and Bob to use quantum mechanics.

And what about string commitment? For what I got, It's a way of committing multiple qubits together in order to achieve a commitment that increases with the number of qubits committed in the strings. But it seems that also string commitment is impossible as well. [2005](http://cds.cern.ch/record/849609/files/0504078.pdf)

So is the research on this topic finished? Is there anything to do on the topic of qubit commitment? Does protocol can commit only z-basis states (such as 0 or 1) or are they able to commit a full qubit (such as any superposition of states).

Comment: "Classical" commitment schemes of interest usually include a protocol to prove knowledge of the value committed.